# Location updates - ignore vague location changes

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to implement google maps with custom user location marker in android app.
I am using `FusedLocationApi` to receive location updates and faced a problem that in onLocationChanged() I receive very different locations each time even when device is not moving, but stays on the one position.
So user position as well as accuracy radius is being changed several times per minute (showing right and wrong position).
I understand that it happened due to receiving location from different sources, but how to determine right and ignore wrong and to vague locations?
Tried to implement a function to ignore wrong location changes, but it doesn't work as expected.
In pictures it looks like for user within a minute (user stays in one position): 
[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

In code

```
private static final long UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = 10000;
private static final long FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS =
            UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS / 2;

// build GoogleApiClient
protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    createLocationRequest();
}
// create location request
protected void createLocationRequest() {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
}

// ... here is how I request the updates
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,mLocationRequest,this);

/**
 * Callback that fires when the location changes.
 */
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO herre I try to figure out which location is right and which is wrong
    if (shouldIgnoreLocationChange(mLastDrawnLocation, location)) {
        return;
    }

    // here i should proceed only with eight location...

}

/**
 * Checks whether location change (coordinates) should be ignored or not
 *
 * @param oldLocation previous {@link Location}
 * @param newLocation new  {@link Location}
 * @return true if coordinates change should be ignored because it is not significant
 */
private boolean shouldIgnoreLocationChange(Location oldLocation, Location newLocation) {
    if (oldLocation == null) {
        // didn't have any location before, so accept new
        return false;
    } else if (null == newLocation || !newLocation.hasAccuracy() || newLocation.getAccuracy() > 150) {
        // new location got invalid or too vague accuracy so ignore it
        return true;
    }

    // ignore change if change is smaller then 3 meters and
    if (oldLocation.distanceTo(newLocation) < 3f && newLocation.getAccuracy() >= oldLocation.getAccuracy()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

However If I use build-in user user location layer - it works perfectly.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the problem but in android documentation it shows and recommend to use

```
    protected void createLocationRequest() {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
}

// ... here is how I request the updates
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,mLocationRequest,this);
```

after you connect your Google client.

[Link to the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html)

Except this, I didnt find any particular errors.

BTW

Which permissions did you request?

You should use `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>`

for `LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY`

Comment: I request updates on onConnected() googleApi callback. And requesting Fine location permission